# Installing protractor on offline machine

Tags: npm, protractor

I have downloaded protractor git repo and tried to install it on my offline machine 
using:

```
npm install <folder-path>
```

it give me the following error:

```
npm err! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
```

I assume it happens because it tries to download all the dependencies from the internet but fails.
Is there a way to install it offline? What files do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm has a local cache, so if you install it once with `npm install protractor`, you'll be able to install it offline next time you need it.
Another solution is just to install it once and the copy all the `node_modules`.

Comment: When talking about local cache, are you referring to the path returned by typing the command `npm config get prefix` or other path?